# Raise an alarm if an EC2 stops working in any case

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a pretty critical EC2 instance with plenty of EIPs associated to it. I have created a Lambda Function which raises a new EC2 with all the necessary secondary IPs and EIPs associated to it, but now I am struggling to find a way to call this function in every scenario where this EC2 could fail.

I would like to be able to call the Lambda function in the following events:

```
1- Someone stops the EC2.
2- Someone Terminates the EC2.
3- Any kind of AWS failure (whole rack, AZ, Region, etc).
```

The third point is easy to achieve with a system check CloudWatch alarm, but I am not sure how to create an alarm to trigger the lambda function (through SNS) if someone stops or terminates the EC2 instance. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: By the way, for these cases, there is autoscaling. You won't need to think of all these when you have it.

Comment: I agree with @Riz. Auto Scaling could automatically launch a replacement instance in _all_ of these situations, and the User Data script could reattach the EIPs, rather than doing it via a Lambda function.

Comment: I tried Auto Scaling + User Data scripts, but I found this solution too slow. In my tests, about 5 minutes for having the new machine running using an AWS AMI while using Lambda it is usually much faster. Maybe I am missing something and there is a way for making it faster with ASG though.

Answer (score 1):

EventBridge can get you notifications to a lambda when certain events happen. For instance,

```
{
  "source": ["aws.ec2"],
  "detail-type": ["EC2 Instance State-change Notification"],
  "detail": {
    "state": ["terminated", "stopped"]
  }
}
```

will trigger when your instances go into 'terminated' or 'stopped' state. There are other states you can look at as well. This will call the lambda for each instance that reaches this state, so you'll need to filter on something as well still.

You might also be able to configure a cloudwatch alarm based on instance metrics and have your lambda run when that alarm fires, which will get you that filtering pre-lambda and save you some invocations if you have a lot of EC2 instance churn in region.

Overall, this sounds like a good job for an autoscaling group, too, if you can get your provisioning logic in the right format.

Comment: Enable termination protection as well, this way it won't be terminated accidently.

Comment: Termination protection is table stakes at this point, I assumed there was some reason for the shutdowns aside from someone going in and clicking "terminate" or similar. But yeah, good call out.

Comment: I am going to try this approach with EventBridge. Thanks for the input.